# Execution of child class' static block derived from abstract class

Tags: java, class, abstract

```
public class Test15 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(B.x);
    }
}

abstract class A { 
    static int x=99;

    A() {
        System.out.println("A DC");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("A SB");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static {
        System.out.println("B Sb");
    }
}
```

Why in the above  program the child class static block is not executed ?

Comment: This access really should be a compiler warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is a `static` variable of class `A`, so even though you access it via `B.x`, there's no need to initialize class `B`. Therefore, class `B`'s `static` initializer is not executed.

Here's the relevant [JLS 12.4.1 quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it, even though it might be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a class that implements an interface.

Comment: But what about class B. Is it loaded or not?

Comment: @ANSHULKUMAR I believe `B` is loaded, based on `Resolution is the process of checking symbolic references from Test to other classes and interfaces, by loading the other classes and interfaces that are mentioned and checking that the references are correct` (`Test` here is the class having the `main` method being executed).

Comment: @ANSHULKUMAR though, reading further, perhaps it's an implementation detail whether B is loaded or not - `An implementation may instead choose to resolve a symbolic reference only when it is actively used; consistent use of this strategy for all symbolic references would represent the "laziest" form of resolution. In this case, if Test had several symbolic references to another class, then the references might be resolved one at a time, as they are used, or perhaps not at all, if these references were never used during execution of the program. `

Comment: @ANSHULKUMAR that said, I'm quite sure `B` must be loaded. Without loading class `B`, we cannot know that `B.x` is not a member of class `B`.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, I just commented on that

Comment: The most direct answer to this would be to `strace` the JVM and watch for access to `B.class`.

Comment: @chrylis yes, though the OP's question is about class initialization, not loading. Loading was only mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

the static block of `B` will be only executed when class `B` is initialized. Calling the feild `x` of its super class `A` will not cause the class `B` to be initialized.

From Java specifacation:

> 12.4.1 When Initialization Occurs
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> • T is a class and an instance of T is created.
>
> • T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
>
> • A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
> • A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
>
> • T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.